# How do I export input text results to an XLS file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xls

I wrote a calculation script using JavaScript and I want to export that result to an XLS file.

This is my code:

```
****************THIS IS MY SCRIPT********
**********PROJECT/PUBLIC/JAVASCRIPT/calculator.js

  $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".conversion input").keyup(multInputs);

     function multInputs() {
         var mult = 0;
         // for each row:
         $("tr.conversion").each(function () {
             // get the values from this row:
             var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
             var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
             var $val3 = $('.val3', this).val();
             var $subtotal = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
             $('.soles',this).text($subtotal);
             mult = ($subtotal*1) +($val3 * 1);

         });

         $("#total").text(mult);
     }
});
```

And this is my view:

```
  <div>
   <table border="1"  class="calculator">
    <tr>
        <th>COSTO DEL DOLAR</th>
        <th>SUMA DE SOLES</th>
        <th>SUMA DE SOLES A DOLARES</th>
        <th>SUMA DE DOLARES</th>
     </tr>
     <tr class="conversion">
        <td>  <input id="cambio"  name="cambio"  class="val1" maxlength ="5"/></td>
        <td>S/<input id="partial" name="partial" class="val2" readonly="readonly"  value="<%=  @soles %>"/></td>
        <td>$ <span class="soles" value="<%=  @multi.to_i %>"></span></td>
        <td>$ <input name="dolares" class="val3" readonly="readonly" value="<%= @dolares.to_i %>"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center">MONTO TOTAL EN DOLARES: $ <span id="total"> 0.00  </span></td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
  </div>
  <%= link_to image_tag("/images/excel.png",:size => "18x18"),{
:controller=>"customer_reports",:action=>"excel",:format=>"xls" ,:search => params[:search]}  %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
def index
   @search = CustomerReport.search(params[:search])
   @customer_reports = @search.paginate( :page => params[:page], :per_page =>10)
   @results = CustomerReport.search(params[:search])

   @soles=CustomerReport.search(params[:search]).find(:all ,:conditions=>"mount_type = '0'").sum(&:mount)
   @dolares=CustomerReport.search(params[:search]).find(:all ,:conditions=>"mount_type = '1'").sum(&:mount) 

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.csv  { render :csv => "reporte_csv",:partial =>"csv" }
     format.xls  { render :xls => "reporte_xls",:partial =>"xls" }
   end
end
```

I want to export my results. Is there other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrote the code in JavaScript, it will execute in the user's browser, and Rails is not in control at that point. You could write the JavaScript's results into a textarea, and have the user copy/paste it into an Excel spreadsheet.

Or, you could submit the result back to Rails as that form's output, and have your Ruby code generate an XLS file, then send that to the browser, to be downloaded by the user.

In my opinion, using JavaScript for the calculation only gets in the way. You should have a form on that page which gathers the needed information. Submit the values from the form to Rails, then have it generate the page, as mentioned in the above paragraph.

Comment: Ok thanks is a good answer but how can i do that?
i understood that i can't export my javascript results,but how can i do to resolve this? do you have any code? or a guide?

Comment: Code or a guide for which part? This isn't a simple, single line of code, sort of question. Do you not know how to receive the output of a form in Rails? If so, that's a very basic part of what Rails does. Or, do you not know how to create a XLS file? Ruby has many gems that allow you to do that, and a search using Google or one of the gems repositories will help you there. HOW to use that gem will be covered by its own documentation as they all differ.